# how does filter2D works in image processing for RGB image to calculate matrix output manually?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, filtering, noise-reduction

I'm newbie in image processing, i have tried to implement filter2D to reduce noise image with RGB color recently, and it works well. But i don't understand how it works manually in image matrix. Anybody can help me to explain how it works manually?
This is the input matrix and output matrix i get.
[Input Image Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPZzP.png)
[Output Image Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAXFq.png)

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

as a short answer, filtering an image means apply a filter (or kernel) to it, i.e; convolving the image by this kernel. For that, you take each pixel on your image and consider a neighbourhood around it. You apply the kernel to the neighbourhood by multiplying each pixel of the neighbourhood with the corresponding kernel coefficient and sum all these values.
For a pixel, this can be summarized by this figure ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/ConvolutionOperations/ConvolutionOperations.html)) :[image: Convolution illustration]

For example, by setting all the coefficients to 1/N (where N is the number of elements in your kernel), you compute the average intensity of your neighbourhood.
You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_discrete_convolution for more information about image convolutions.

[OpenCV's documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html) gives some practical examples of image smoothing.

Hope it helps